# The Chair recognizes [azure-form-recognizer] and not [form-recognizer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Today I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73140875) that had both [form-recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-recognizer) and [azure-form-recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-form-recognizer) applied to it.

The anemic tag excerpt (and identical wiki) associated with [form-recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-recognizer) (168):

> This tag is designed to track questions and discussions related to Microsoft Azure Form Recognizer API, usage, and other feedback.

<sub>(Apparently Stack Overflow now allows "discussions" and "other feedback" in addition to programming questions)</sub>

There is no tag wiki on [azure-form-recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-form-recognizer) (76).

I suggest we merge the tags under [azure-form-recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-form-recognizer) as that follows the other tags about Microsoft Azure services, including:

- [azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops)
- [azure-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-functions)
- [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb)
- [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure*)

The tag excerpt should be something along the lines of:

> Use this tag for questions about programming with the Azure Form Recognizer.

The tag wiki should be something like:

> The [Azure Form Recognizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/), part of Microsoft's Azure Applied AI Service collection, uses machine learning to extract key-value pairs, tables, and text data from documents. There is a [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-rest-api), as well as SDKs for several languages:
>
> - [C# SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-csharp-sdk)
> - [Java SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-java-sdk)
> - [JavaScript SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-javascript-sdk)
> - [Python SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/try-v3-python-sdk)
>
> As with all questions on Stack Overflow, questions using this tag must be related to a programming task to remain on topic.

<sub>I would have submitted this as a tag wiki edit but apparently the queue is full, or for whatever reason I am unable to edit it.</sub>

Comment: The first paragraph should also be included in the tag excerpt. The tag excerpt can use definitions about the topic. Also, is "programming with the Azure Form Recognizer" even possible?

Comment: "but apparently the queue is full" -- as a sub-20k user, you suggest tag wikis. Those edits go through the regular suggested edits queue, so if it hits 500 pending tasks, you don't get to suggest wikis. You can review a few edits (to anything, questions and answer edits still reduce the count) in another tab, and go back every few minutes and smack the button until it submits

Comment: Queue weirdness aside... I'm seeing [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bform-recognizer%5D+-%5Bazure%5D+-%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bazure*%5D+-%5Bmicrosoft*%5D&searchOn=3) not tagged C# or [azure]. Have any and all non-Azure questions had the tag removed?

Comment: @Braiam Well, as noted in the proposed tag wiki, it has a REST API and SDKs in four different programming languages, so, yes, I would say that "programming with the Azure Form Recognizer" is possible. I assume it would be integrated into a workflow; someone scans a paper document, AFR scans the image/PDF and returns some JSON, some other code takes the JSON and does something clever with it.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It doesn't even show an edit button/link on the tag info page ‍♂️. I've edited other tag wikis in the past, so I'm not sure what changed. I'm not surprised by questions not tagged [c#] as they have SDKs for other languages. As for [azure]... many of them are tagged with [azure-cognitive-services] so I guess that was enough for some. I've been looking through them and have yet to find one that *isn't* about the Azure product. Amazingly, Microsoft found a good, unique name for a product!

Comment: IIRC, the link is hidden if the page is loaded while the queue is full. There aren't any pending edits on the wiki at least, FWIW. Anyway, good enough for me; I'll fix the synonym

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Yeah, it showed up and I've suggested the edits: [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32349423) [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32349422). Thanks.